# Reading data into a void* variable in struct

Tags: c++, pointers, struct

I have a struct SInfoEntry to store data that I read from a [VCF file](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variant_Call_Format).

```
struct SInfoEntry
{
   int type; //Info Type
   std::string key; //Info Tag
   void* values = NULL; //Data
   int n; //Len
};
```

In the code below, I am trying to store my data in ***values*** variable in my  struct. However I am getting error when I am trying to do that:

```
SInfoEntry infoEntry;
//This line is giving me EXC_BAD_ACCESS exception
bcf_get_info_values(m_pHeader, m_pRecord, "AF", (void**)(&infoEntry.values), &infoEntry.n, BCF_HT_REAL);
```

However instead if I declare a local array, the function successfully return me the data I want:

```
void* values = NULL;
int   nvalue;
bcf_get_info_values(m_pHeader, m_pRecord, "AF", (void**)(&values), &nvalue, BCF_HT_REAL);
```

Why is that trying to read data into struct fails? Am I missing something in pointer arithmetic?

I am using ***'bcf_get_info_values'*** function from an external library and  here is the signature of the function:

```
int bcf_get_info_values(const bcf_hdr_t *hdr, bcf1_t *line, const char *tag, void **dst, int *ndst, int type);
```

**Edit:** [Here](https://nvlabs.github.io/nvbio/vcf_8c_source.html#l02853) is the Link of the source of **bcf_get_info_values** function. As I can see, I do not need to allocate memory since the function is using realloc().

Comment: I don't know what `bcf_get_info_values` does, but I suspect `values` is expected to point to a buffer of length `n`.

Comment: i suspect both are invalid, you are just betting different UB.

Comment: A google search finds the source code [here](https://nvlabs.github.io/nvbio/vcf_8c_source.html#l02853). It looks like it's expecting those vars to be initialized.

Answer (score 0):

What you are actually doing is coping data to an unallocated memory space.

In the first example it is probably initialized to NULL, hence the app crashed.
the second example is just coping data to random memory places, this shouldnt work and is extremely dangerous.

you can do one of the following:

Declare an array with size as the maximum object size you want to put in it:

```
uint8_t values[1000];
int   nvalue;
bcf_get_info_values(m_pHeader, m_pRecord, "AF", (void**)(&values), &nvalue, BCF_HT_REAL);
```

Or allocate the array dynamically:

```
void* values = malloc(size); 
int   nvalue;
bcf_get_info_values(m_pHeader, m_pRecord, "AF", (void**)(&values), &nvalue, BCF_HT_REAL);
```

Comment: `bcf_get_info_values` is supposed to fill the pointer. Otherwise there would be no reason to pass a `void**`.